# Convergence of complex dilatation of composed quasiconformal mappings

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, approximation, measurable-functions, quasiconformal-maps

My question refers to the notion of *good approximation* of quasiconformal mappings: Let $G, G' \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be domains. A sequence $(f_n)_n$ of quasiconformal mappings of $G$ onto $G'$ is called a *good approximation* of a quasiconformal mapping $f: G \rightarrow G'$ if the $f_n$ converge locally uniformly to $f$ and the corresponding complex dilatations $\mu_n := \mu_{f_n}$ converge to the complex dilatation $\mu_f$ of $f$ almost everywhere (a.e.) in $G$ (for certain reasons, I'm not taking into account whether the quasiconformal mappings $f_n$, $g_n$, $f$ and $g$ have uniformly bounded maximal dilatation $K \in [1, \infty)$). The complex dilatations $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ are supposed to be measurable functions in $G$ (hence, in particular, not necessarily continuous).

Now suppose the sequences of quasiconformal mappings $(f_n)_n$ and $(g_n)_n$ are good approximations of the quasiconformal mappings $f: G \rightarrow G$ and $g: G \rightarrow G$ , respectively, of the same domain $G$ - in other words, the mappings $f_n, g_n, f$ and $g$ are self-mappings of the domain $G$ (mainly for the sake of simplicity). Hence, one may consider the composition $(f_n \circ g_n)_n$ and $f \circ g$ as well as the complex dilatations of the composed mappings: $(\mu_{f_n \circ g_n})_n$ and $\mu_{f \circ g}$. Note that there exists a general formula for the complex dilatation of composed mappings (see for example Lehto/Virtanen, "*Quasiconformal Mappings in the Plane*", formula (5.6), p. 183):
$$
\mu_{f \circ g}(z) = \frac{\mu_g(z) + \mu_f(g(z)) \cdot e^{-2i \operatorname{arg}(g_z(z))}}{1 + \mu_g(z) \cdot \mu_f(g(z))\cdot e^{-2i \operatorname{arg}(g_{\overline{z}}(z))}} \tag{1}
$$
for a.e. $z \in G$. My question focuses on the convergence behaviour of the sequence $(\mu_{f_n \circ g_n})_n$:

> Under the above-mentioned assumptions, does the sequence of complex dilatations $(\mu_{f_n \circ g_n})_n$ converge pointwise (a.e.) towards the composition $\mu_{f \circ g}$ in $G$?

So far, I tried to use the mentioned formula (1). More precisely, my intention was to show that the term $\mu_{f_n}(g_n(z))$ converges to $\mu_f(g(z))$ as follows:
$$
| \mu_{f_n}(g_n(z)) - \mu_f(g(z)) | \leq | \mu_{f_n}(g_n(z)) - \mu_{f_n}(g(z)) | + | \mu_{f_n}(g(z)) - \mu_f(g(z)) |
$$
Clearly, the second term on the right-hand side tends to zero as $n \to \infty$. But I'm having trouble with the first term $| \mu_{f_n}(g_n(z)) - \mu_{f_n}(g(z)) |$. Can we actually show that this term tends to zero as well for $n \to \infty$? I thought of maybe using the modulus of continuity of $\mu_{f_n}$ here somehow, but didn't succeed on this yet (note, however, that the complex dilatations are *not* supposed to be continuous)...More generally, is there maybe a known result, theorem etc. that solves the described problem?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is $\mu_{f_n}$ continuous? This wasn't stated. In general, a counterexample would be $f_n=f$ with dilatation being, say $\frac12\chi_E$ where $E$ is a fat Cantor set, and $g_n(z) = z-1/n$ or some such sequence of shifts.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! No, the $\mu_{f_n}$ are not assumed to be continuous, but rather measurable, so I'm considering the general situation. The very same holds for the $\mu_{g_n}$. As for your mentioned example: It is $\mu_{g_n} = \mu_g = 0$ with ($g(z) = z$) and $\mu_{f_n} = \mu_f = \frac{1}{2} \chi_E$. Then $$\mu_{f \circ g} = \frac{1}{2} \chi_E$$ which is zero a.e. since $E$ is a Cantor set. The same is true for the complex dilatation $\mu_{f_n \circ g_n}$ of the composed mappings...I don't quite see where the contradiction lies in here? Beside this, what do you mean by a "*fat*" Cantor set?

Comment: [You could Google it, you know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set)

Comment: Yes, that's what i probably should've done ;-) Thanks! But to be honest, I still don't see what the point of your mentioned example is in order to establish a counterexample to my question. Could you please explain it?